# Find the width of tree at each level/height (non-binary tree)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Dear experienced friends, I am looking for an algorithm (Python) that outputs the width of a tree at each level. Here are the input and expected outputs.

(I have updated the problem with a more complex edge list. The original question with sorted edge list can be elegantly solved by @Samwise answer.)

---

**Input** (Edge List: source-->target)

```
[[11,1],[11,2],
[10,11],[10,22],[10,33],
[33,3],[33,4],[33,5],[33,6]]
```

The tree graph looks like this:

```
       10
    /   |  \
   11   22  33
   / \    / | \ \
  1   2  3  4  5 6
```

**Expected Output** (Width of each level/height)

```
[1,3,6] # according to the width of level 0,1,2
```

---

I have looked through the web. It seems this topic related to [BFS](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/description/) and [Level Order Traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-width-of-a-binary-tree/). However, most solutions are based on the binary tree. How can solve the problem when the tree is not binary (e.g. the above case)?

(I'm new to the algorithm, and any references would be really appreciated. Thank you!)

Comment: You can BFS and Queue to travel the tree and calculate the size of each level.

Comment: Remember: DFS solves many problems although it's always the worst way to solve them. @dmitryro gave you the right answer: always use BFS, in competitive programming and in life 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient, but it requires only two scans over the edge list, so it's optimal up to a constant factor. It places no requirement on the order of the edges in the edge list, but does insist that each edge be (source, dest). Also, doesn't check that the edge list describes a connected tree (or a tree at all; if the edge list is cyclic, the program will never terminate).

```py
from collections import defauiltdict

# Turn the edge list into a (non-binary) tree, represented as a
# dictionary whose keys are the source nodes with the list of children
# as its value.
def edge_list_to_tree(edges):
    '''Given a list of (source, dest) pairs, constructs a tree.
       Returns a tuple (tree, root) where root is the root node
       and tree is a dict which maps each node to a list of its children.
       (Leaves are not present as keys in the dictionary.)
    ''' 
    tree = defaultdict(list)
    sources = set()  # nodes used as sources
    dests = set()    # nodes used as destinations
    for source, dest in edges:
        tree[source].append(dest)
        sources.add(source)
        dests.add(dest)
    roots = sources - dests      # Source nodes which are not destinations
    assert(len(roots) == 1)      # There is only one in a tree
    tree.default_factory = None  # Defang the defaultdict
    return tree, roots.pop()

# A simple breadth-first-search, keeping the count of nodes at each level.
def level_widths(tree, root):
    '''Does a BFS of tree starting at root counting nodes at each level.
       Returns a list of counts.
    '''
    widths = []         # Widths of the levels
    fringe = [root]     # List of nodes at current level
    while fringe:
        widths.append(len(fringe))
        kids = []       # List of nodes at next level
        for parent in fringe:
            if parent in tree:
                for kid in tree[parent]:
                    kids.append(kid)
        fringe = kids   # For next iteration, use this level's kids
    return widths

# Put the two pieces together.
def tree_width(edges):
    return level_widths(*edge_list_to_tree(edges))
```

Comment: Thank you @rici. Your answer perfectly solve this question. The descriptions alongside the code are also helpful. Beautiful code!

Answer (score 2):

Build a dictionary of the "level" of each node, and then count the number of nodes at each level:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def tree_width(edges):
...     levels = {}  # {node: level}
...     for [p, c] in edges:
...         levels[c] = levels.setdefault(p, 0) + 1
...     widths = Counter(levels.values())  # {level: width}
...     return [widths[level] for level in sorted(widths)]
...
>>> tree_width([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],
... [1,4],[1,5],
... [3,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]])
[1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Elegant Solution. Thank you @Samwise. However, I found that this method requires us to make sure that the parent nodes show before the child nodes. For example, if we shuffle the edge list: [[3,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9],[1,4],[1,5],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]. Then the results will be wrong --- as it cannot update the level of earlier nodes.

Comment: I just updated the question to make it more clear. But your answer is already very helpful enough. I am thinking the variance of this question (which might be more robust). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution that is based on Width-First-Traversal
In Width-First-Traversal we add the node to the array, but in this solution we put the array in an object together with its level and then add it to the array.

```js
function levelWidth(root) {
    const counter = [];
    const traverseBF = fn => {
        const arr = [{n: root, l:0}];
        const pushToArr = l => n => arr.push({n, l});
        while (arr.length) {
            const node = arr.shift();
            node.n.children.forEach(pushToArr(node.l+1));
            fn(node);
        }
    };    
    traverseBF(node => {
        counter[node.l] = (+counter[node.l] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return counter;
}
```